# Angularjs basic example not working in fiddle

Tags: angularjs

I have to build basic sample in angularjs but it seems not working there. I am not getting what I am doing wrong. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09r62gL2/1/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "my name";
})
```

Comment: You can show the rest  too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You didn't choose angular version there.
- You choose load type onLoad which won't work for angular.

Follow like the Image

[image]

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/9uh5r0n2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name= "jitender";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">  
  <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>